# Using LOAD DATA INFILE statement when csv table headings don't match mySQL table headings?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, load-data-infile

What I'm looking to do is import some **.CSV** files into **mySQL** using **php**.

I'm going to be using the **LOAD DATA INFILE** statement but I have an issue:

The headers in the .CSV file don't match up with the columns in the mySQL table, there are way more in the .CSV file. I know I can ignore certain columnhs by using a variable like:

```
$insert_query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE $csvfile
            INTO table $tableName
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            LINES TERMINATED BY ''
            (col1,col2,col3,@ignore,col4)";
```

What I would like to know is if I can assign the columns of data in the .CSV file to different columns in the mySQL table, E.G mapping the first column of data in the .CSV to the fifth column of the mySQL table, kind of like:

```
$insert_query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE $csvfile
            INTO table $tableName
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            LINES TERMINATED BY ''
            (col5,col2,col3,@ignore,col4)";
```

Is this possible? If so, some examples would be greatly appreciated! :)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question. You should provide an example and say what result is desired. Easiest way is often to load the infile into an empty (temporary) table and then process this data in a proper way to fill existing tables / data structures.

Comment: I've edited the question to better explain my question. Thanks! :)

Comment: You are showing a correct example, this should work as intended. Be aware that this approach of generating SQL in PHP is highly vulnerable to SQL injection. Never use this form of interpolation in conjunction with user input data. $csvfile and $tableName should come from hard coded non-public accessible server script only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this using the appropriate syntax for your problem and  specify a column list:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/to/your/file' INTO TABLE yourTable (col1,col2,...);
```

The [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) states further:

> You must also specify a column list if the order of the fields in the
>   input file differs from the order of the columns in the table.
>   Otherwise, MySQL cannot tell how to match input fields with table
>   columns.

Comment: I've altered my question to be more specific, is the column list the location the .csv columns will fill? E.G the first column on my .CSV file would populate the second column of my mySQL table if I wrote (col2, cola, colb, colc, coletc)?

Comment: @LazyTotoro Yes, that is exactly what I wrote in my answer. You can even add computed columns, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569704/mysql-load-data-infile-store-line-number/23570525#23570525

Comment: one brief additional question: I would replace col1, col2, col3 with the actual column names from my name so 'name', 'age' ect?

Comment: @LazyTotoro Yes, exactly those column names.