# mysql: Reading in CSV files: Whitespace issues

Tags: php, python, mysql

I have tried to import a CSV file into a mysql database using the LOAD DATA INFILE function. However I keep getting warnings that the data is being truncated.

However, the actual problem is that the fields in the CSV file appear to be tab separated in addition to being comma separated. Thus, what is actually being truncated is the whitespace/tab spaces and not any usual information.

How do I deal with this issue? Is there some way to ignore white spaces all together using just mySQL? Would I have to use Python or PHP to come up with some other solution?

Comment: Are all your columns of a data type that's big enough for the import?

Comment: Yes. I think the largest field is a string of at most 30 characters.

Comment: Then you got to determine which data is affected. You could adapt the approach of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569704/mysql-load-data-infile-store-line-number/23570525 with a line number column.