# .csv import has random Chinese characters (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I am currently making a mysql database. When I import data from a .csv file holding my companies records, about half of it gets imported normally while the other half gets changed to the same Chinese characters. At first I thought it was the Heidisql tool but after doing a manual load in mysql I still had Chinese characters in the data. Here is an example of the load statement (sorry if it doesn't format right):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/text.csv'
INTO TABLE test 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

In the pathing above, that is not the actual path it is similar to it. The pathing is correct as no errors were given when that was executed.

After I imported the data I used SELECT and UNION ALL to display my data (with another table because that is one of the major goals of this project). Below is that code snippet:

```
SELECT PartNum, Description, Quantity, Price, '','' FROM Test1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Test2
```

The two single quote areas are because the Test1 table has 2 less columns than that of the Test2 table. I was getting an error because the Test1 table had fewer columns and I read that this was a workaround. Now to the issue. My first instinct, upon seeing the Chinese characters, was to try a manual load (opposed to Heidisql). After this did not help, my first thought was to check the .csv file. However, I inspected the table and saw that it was arranged alphabetically. My .csv file is not arranged that way. I have no start point or end point to go off of to inspect the .csv file. As a mysql noob, I thought it would be quicker to ask if anyone knows of anything to help me get these rows back to English. Examples of the Chinese characters are the following: 䍏䱌䕃呏剓㩍䌱㔲㌰㐱㠺䵃ㄵ㈱㌭㈭㌰㐱㠭啎, 䙌䵉千䕌䱁久何区吱〰䵓, etc.

Comment: I assume your CSV file hasn't got any Chinese characters in the content. You could set the character set with `[CHARACTER SET charset_name]`, see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) and to see, where it fails, you could try to import in a new table with an additional column for the row number and set this row number like I showed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569704/mysql-load-data-infile-store-line-number/23570525#23570525

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Using `mysqlimport` instead solved the issue for me.