# how to increment variable value by 1 for each record with php mysql LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I am trying to save an incrementing value for one of the columns using LOAD DATA INFILE method (csv data to database). Nothing I am trying is working. without the extra serial_no field everything imports fine, and if i set a hard coded value to serial_no, that works too. Just can't get it to increase the numerical value by 1 for each record.

--

```
$loadsqlfiletodb = "SET @a:=".$serial_no_max_new.";
        LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$target_file."'
        INTO TABLE ".DB_NAME2.".list_data
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        IGNORE 1 LINES 
        (first,last,address,city,state,zip,company,tracking_number,vin,year,make,model,rough,average,clean,misc1,misc2,misc3,misc4,misc5,misc6,misc7,misc8,misc9,misc10,list,email,phone,image_name,image_path)
        SET cid = ".$campaignid.",
            jid = ".$jobid.",
            serial_no = @a:=@a+1 ";

        mysql_query($loadsqlfiletodb) or die(mysql_error());
```

--

```
$loadsqlfiletodb = "
        SET @a:='".$serial_no_max_new."'
        LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$target_file."'
        INTO TABLE ".DB_NAME2.".list_data
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        IGNORE 1 LINES 
        (first,last,address,city,state,zip,company,tracking_number,vin,year,make,model,rough,average,clean,misc1,misc2,misc3,misc4,misc5,misc6,misc7,misc8,misc9,misc10,list,email,phone,image_name,image_path)
        SET cid = ".$campaignid.",
            jid = ".$jobid.",
            serial_no = @a:=@a+1 ";

        mysql_query($loadsqlfiletodb) or die(mysql_error());
```

--

```
$loadsqlfiletodb = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$target_file."'
        INTO TABLE ".DB_NAME2.".list_data
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        IGNORE 1 LINES 
        (first,last,address,city,state,zip,company,tracking_number,vin,year,make,model,rough,average,clean,misc1,misc2,misc3,misc4,misc5,misc6,misc7,misc8,misc9,misc10,list,email,phone,image_name,image_path)
        SET cid = ".$campaignid.",
            jid = ".$jobid.",
            serial_no = ".$serial_no_max_new."+1 ";

        mysql_query($loadsqlfiletodb) or die(mysql_error());
```

--

```
$loadsqlfiletodb = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$target_file."'
        INTO TABLE ".DB_NAME2.".list_data
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        IGNORE 1 LINES 
        (first,last,address,city,state,zip,company,tracking_number,vin,year,make,model,rough,average,clean,misc1,misc2,misc3,misc4,misc5,misc6,misc7,misc8,misc9,misc10,list,email,phone,image_name,image_path)
        SET cid = ".$campaignid.",
            jid = ".$jobid.",
            serial_no = ".$serial_no_max_new." = ".$serial_no_max_new."+1 ";

        mysql_query($loadsqlfiletodb) or die(mysql_error());
```

update:

here is the full thing. serial number is always going to be 9 digits. no more, no less. when serial reaches 999999999, the next recorded serial will be 000000000. however, don't worry about the nines to zeros part. at this time i am trying to figure out how to increment value by 1 for that column using the LOAD DATA INFILE method of importing file to database.

```
$query_max = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT id, latest_serial_no FROM ".DB_NAME2.".latest_serial_number WHERE id=1"), MYSQL_ASSOC);
        $serial_no_max = $query_max["latest_serial_no"];
        $serial_no_max_new = $serial_no_max;
        if ($serial_no_max > 999999998) {$serial_no_max_new = 000000000;}

        $padd = "";
        $serial_len = strlen($serial_no_max_new);
        if($serial_len < 9) {
            $serial_len = (9 - $serial_len);
            for($is=0;$is<$serial_len;$is++) {
                $padd .= "0";
            }
            $serial_no_max_new = $padd . $serial_no_max_new;
        }
        $query_serial = trim($serial_no_max_new);
        //echo "q_s: ".$query_serial;

        //Import uploaded file to Database
        //$target_file is where the uploaded file is located

        $loadsqlfiletodb = "SET @a:=".$query_serial.";
        LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$target_file."'
        INTO TABLE ".DB_NAME2.".list_data
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        IGNORE 1 LINES 
        (first,last,address,city,state,zip,company,tracking_number,vin,year,make,model,rough,average,clean,misc1,misc2,misc3,misc4,misc5,misc6,misc7,misc8,misc9,misc10,list,email,phone,image_name,image_path)
        SET cid = ".$campaignid.",
            jid = ".$jobid.",
            serial_no = @a:=@a+1 ";

        mysql_query($loadsqlfiletodb) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Use an auto_increment column.

Comment: it needs to go back to 0 and start over again on a certain condition, so can't use autoincrement field type.

Comment: I don't see any condition in your code. This is what you wrote: "increase the numerical value by 1 for each record". However - you can update the column after loading the csv.

Comment: Would you be able to have part of your program add a new row that sets your column value to 0 and it just increments from 0 again with autoincrementation?

Comment: i don't know what that means or how to accomplish.

Comment: i'm not even sure that's going to work for automatically going from 999999999 to 000000000, because that query is only done once then the LOAD DATA INFILE script does it's thing. gonna have to do the check inline with that INFILE code. i used to have all this importing from csv to database a different way where it looped through all the lines of csv one by one, but now i am trying to convert to LOAD DATA INFILE. right now i just need to know how to increment that serial value by one in the LOAD DATA INFILE section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
 /*1 get last serial number.

 open csv file.
 foreach row in csv file:
    increment serial number.
    if max number
       set serial number to 0.
    add new field to csv row

 close csv file

 insert csv to database*/


    $query_max = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT id, latest_serial_no FROM ".DB_NAME2.".latest_serial_number WHERE id=1"), MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $serial_no_max = $query_max["latest_serial_no"];
    $serial_no_max_new = $serial_no_max;
    if ($serial_no_max > 999999998) {$serial_no_max_new = 000000000;}

    $padd = "";
    $serial_len = strlen($serial_no_max_new);
    if($serial_len < 9) {
        $serial_len = (9 - $serial_len);
        for($is=0;$is<$serial_len;$is++) {
            $padd .= "0";
        }
        $serial_no_max_new = $padd . $serial_no_max_new;
    }
    $query_serial = trim($serial_no_max_new);
    //echo "q_s: ".$query_serial;

    // Add serail number to csv code
    $csv = fopen($target_file, "r");
    $tmp_csv_addr = $target_file . "2";
    $tmp_csv = fopen($tmp_csv_addr, "a");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($csv, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $data[] = $query_serial;
        fputcsv($tmp_csv, $data, ",");
    }
    fclose($csv);
    fclose($tmp_csv);

    // Insert into database
    $loadsqlfiletodb = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$tmp_csv_addr."'
    INTO TABLE ".DB_NAME2.".list_data
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES 
    (first,last,address,city,state,zip,company,tracking_number,vin,year,make,model,rough,average,clean,misc1,misc2,misc3,misc4,misc5,misc6,misc7,misc8,misc9,misc10,list,email,phone,image_name,image_path,serial_no)
    SET cid = ".$campaignid.",
        jid = ".$jobid;

    mysql_query($loadsqlfiletodb) or die(mysql_error());

    unlink($tmp_csv);
```

Comment: would "make tmp file address" be better like this: "tmp_csv_addr.csv"? what is the "a" in fopen? what is the while loop doing?

Comment: Yes, create temporary address for new CSV file. And copy CSV on $target_file to new file. But also add new field to temporary file. Field will contain `serial_no` value.

Comment: 'a' in fopen means, open file to writing and put pointer to the end. So data will be appended.

Comment: Through while loop, 1) Increment `serial_no` value 1) Copy row from $target_file to Temporary CSV file (but adding new field to row, which will contain incremented `serial_no`).

Comment: Then, loading into table, temporary CSV. And delete it with *unlink()* function

Comment: getting this error: Can't find file ''.
that means i didn't copy the original file to another file? how is the new field added to new file? is that code there in that example?

Comment: @leoarce Create your own name for Temporary CSV. For example `$target_file."2"` or something else ))

Comment: is this line right? $tmp_csv = fopen($tmp_csv, "a"); shouldn't it be $tmp_csv = fopen($tmp_csv_addr, "a"); ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't see it.

Comment: it's creating copy of file but now getting this error: Can't find file 'Resource id #59'.

Comment: Talk in chat? Join   http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/111049/how-to-increment-variable-value-by-1-for-each-record-with-php-mysql-load-data-inf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111050/discussion-between-leoarce-and-medet-ahmetson-atabayev).

Answer (score 0):

Load your data into the table with an an auto_incement column (id).

After that run an update:

```sql
UPDATE list_data
SET serail_no = MOD(id, 1000000000)
```

Comment: i don't know about that. can i get some help from someone else please?